# How do you determine the size of the nodes created by a 'std::map' for use with 'boost::pool_allocator' (in a cross-platform way)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, boost, pool

**UPDATE**

Per comments, answer, and additional research, I have come to the conclusion that there is typically no difference between a `set` and a `map` in terms of node overhead.  My question that follows is really:

> How do you determine node overhead for convenient use of
>   `boost::pool_allocator` as a custom allocator?

And, a further **update**: The node overhead is probably never going to be more than the size of 4 pointers, so just purging the Boost Pool for `sizeof(T)`, `sizeof(T)+sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(T) + 2*sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(T) + 3*sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(T) + 4*sizeof(int)` (or `int64_t` for 64-bit systems) should be fine.  That is what I am actually doing, and it works.

---

I want to use a [boost memory pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) to manage tens of millions of tiny, identically-sized objects by avoiding calls to the destructors of these objects, and instead freeing the memory in single swaths containing many instances per swath.

I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942255/how-to-prevent-destructors-from-being-called-on-objects-managed-by-boostfast-p) about this issue, and the answer to that question has led me to understand that the question I *really* need to answer is the one I am asking here.

Consider the following code:

```
class Obj { // ... has an operator<() ... };

typedef std::set<Obj, std::less<Obj>, boost::fast_pool_allocator<Obj>> fast_set_obj;

// Deliberately do not use a managed pointer -
// I will *NOT* delete this object, but instead
// I will manage the memory using the memory pool!!!
fast_set_obj * mset = new fast_set_obj;

// ... add some Obj's to 'mset'
mset->insert(Obj());
mset->insert(Obj());

// Do something desireable with the set ...
...

// All done.
// It's time to release the memory, but do NOT call any Obj destructors.
// The following line of code works exactly as intended.

boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(Obj const)>::purge_memory();
```

If you step into the `purge_memory()` function of the last line of code, you will see that the `fast_pool_allocator` nicely proceeds to free the memory from the system, just as desired. (No `Obj` destructors are called, because as noted in the linked question above, the job of the custom allocator is **just** to allocate and free memory, **not** to call constructors or destructors.)

It works precisely as desired.  Great!

However, here is the problem.  If you replace the `set` with a `map`, and then try to use the `boost::pool_allocator`, **nothing happens** in the call to `purge_memory()`!

```
typedef std::map<int, int, std::less<int>,
                 boost::fast_pool_allocator<std::pair<int const, int>>>
        fast_map_obj;

// Ditto above: Deliberately do not use managed pointer
mast_map_obj * mmap = new fast_map_obj;

mmap[5] = Obj();
mmap[6] = Obj();

...

// Uh-oh.  The following line of code DOES NOTHING, because I was using a map, not a set!

boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag,
                     sizeof(std::pair<int const, int>)>::purge_memory();
```

As noted, the last line of code **does nothing**.  The reason is that the `boost::fast_pool_allocator` is a singleton that only responds to, and manages memory for, objects [of a given size that is fixed at compile-time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/pooling.html#boost_pool.pool.pooling.simple).  This is why the `sizeof` argument is used in the expression that calls `purge_memory()` - it tells the Boost Pool code *which* of the various *different* singleton memory pools to purge (assuming the requested one exists due to previously having been instantiated).

Unfortunately, because the memory pool selected to be purged is size-dependent, it is *critical* that the size of the internal objects managed (i.e., created and destroyed in memory allocated via calls to the custom allocator) is known.  Sadly, for `std::map`, the size of the internal objects managed by the `map` is neither `sizeof(Obj)` nor `sizeof(std::pair<int const, Obj>)`.

My question is: How do you rigorously, and in a cross-platform way that works according to the C++11 standard, determine the size of the objects internally managed by `std::map` for use with `boost::fast_pool_allocator`?

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is kind of weird your example works with std::set, but not with std::map, because internally they use the same node type (_Rb_tree_node<value_type> in libstdc++; quite probably size rounding is at work in the singleton pool). Unfortunately, this type (and the actual tree member) are private, so you can't look at them from outside.

Comment: All examples in the Boost Pool documentation involve lists and sets - none involve maps.  Also, I have read elsewhere that `map` nodes do not stor `pair`s.

Comment: At least in libstdc++ map (Rb_tree) nodes do store map::value_type as is (so it will be pair). And std::list<> is not really that different from std::set or std::map, the only difference is the size of overhead (2 pointers for list, circa 4 pointers for set and map).

Comment: I don't think it's true that the size of objects allocated internally by `map` when it calls the custom allocator is the size of `std::pair<K const, V>`, while I think it *is* true that the size of objects allocated internally by `set` when it calls the custom allocator is the size of `K const`.

Comment: Why don't you check the source and see for yourself? stl is open source on all platforms I'm aware of.

Comment: I am doing that right now.  It is likely to require hours, if not days, for me to understand, to be able to answer the question.  The internals of `std::map` are extremely intricate.  Perhaps you can understand it more quickly?

Comment: The pool pertains to the internal storage of the container. The container uses the allocator's `rebind` member to create a new allocator that works for the types used in the implementation. Note that your `set` or `map` itself will _not_ be allocated in the pool: only the internal storage.

Comment: @oakad - Apparently, there is a specialization for `std::set<int>` for which the node size is the size of an `int` (see Nevin's answer); but for more complex types, there is additional node overhead.  I was wrong (and you're almost certainly right) that there's 'typically' no difference in node storage overhead between a `set` and a `map` - I was fooled because the `set` I was testing with stored `ints`.

Comment: On your platform they probably went with "sorted array" approach for integral type sets (btw, which toolchain are you using?). From what I understand, this was ok as long as older C++ standards are concerned, but should not be done in C++11 (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @oakad - If it works for `int`'s, I would think it would work just as well for any other POD to use a sorted array and avoid the node overhead (the C++11 standard notwithstanding)... I wonder if it tests for the trait `is_pod`?

Comment: Suddenly: boost/container/flat_set.hpp and boost/container/flat_map.hpp

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't know the internal type which `set` uses for nodes.

While I haven't figured out how to determine this at compile time, you can write a tracing allocator which prints out the `sizeof` the node type when `allocate` is called, as in:

```
template<typename T>
struct SimpleAllocator : private std::allocator<T>
{
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = typename std::allocator<T>::pointer;
    using size_type = typename std::allocator<T>::size_type;

    pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {   
        std::cout << "Allocator sizeof(T)==" << sizeof(T) << '\n';
        return std::allocator<T>::allocate(n);
    }   

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
    { return std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, n); }
};
```

And a little test program (I'm testing with sets of ints):

```
std::set<int, std::less<int>, SimpleAllocator<int>> s;
s.insert(2);
```

On my system, I get output of:

> Allocator sizeof(T)==32

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a truly cross platform way to deduce what you are after, since every map implementation is unhappy in its own way, but generally it is the map node that will be allocated in the pool.

This looks different for the different implementations of the standard library, so you code will have to `#ifdef`-ed for the different versions. With a fragility warning in place, here are the main ones for the g++/clang++/msc compilers and their std libs:

```
// libstdc++
boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag,
    sizeof(std::_Rb_tree_node<fast_map_obj::value_type>)>::purge_memory()

// libc++
boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag,
    sizeof(std::__tree_node<fast_map_obj::value_type, void*>)>::purge_memory()

// msvc 2013 (incl. nov ctp)
boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag,
    sizeof(fast_map_obj::_Node)>::purge_memory()
```

Here are some useful links for finding the necessary defines:

> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/config/compiler/
>
> http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/

Comment: Might I be right that a good proposal for an enhancement of `boost::pool_allocator` would be for the allocator to determine for itself the correct underlying pool to use, seeing as it is associated with one and only one container of known `K, V`?