# How to allocate std::map's internal RB_tree node in memory pool in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, allocator

`std::map` definition is copied below:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

Based on `std::map` definition, we can provider customized allocator for its **Key** and **Value**.

Questions:

1. In most situations, `std::map` is implemented by RB tree. How can we provide customized allocator for RB tree node? I am afraid that we can not do it.
2. If the answer to the first question is that we can **NOT** provide customized allocator for RB tree node, we can **NOT** provide customized allocator for other node-based containers (for example, `std::lis`t and `std::set`), either. Please confirm if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you provide a custom allocator, all nodes will be allocated using the provided allocator.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need to know the node size to calculate the memory pool size. They are using the same allocator, but it allocates memory size of _Rb_tree_node instead of std::pair<const Key, T>.

Comment: The size of a map node depends on the STL implementation. If I remember correctly, on my system it was the size of the pair plus 3 * `sizeof(std::size_t)` which comes from node the pointers. Maybe the following link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951378/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-the-nodes-created-by-a-stdmap-for-use-with

Comment: thanks, it is much safer to use _Rb_tree_node instead of the size of the pair plus 3 * sizeof(std::size_t)

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, the allocator type that you provide as a `map` template argument is used also for allocation of nodes (namely its `allocate` member function). You can observe this, for example, in the [source code of libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h#L146):

```
typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
   rebind<value_type>::other _Pair_alloc_type;

typedef _Rb_tree<key_type, value_type, _Select1st<value_type>,
    key_compare, _Pair_alloc_type> _Rep_type;
```

The original allocator parameter `_Alloc` of `std::map` is *rebound* to a map's value type and passed as a template argument to `_Rb_tree`. There, the allocator is again [rebound to the node type `_Rb_tree_node<_Val>`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h#L438):

```
typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
   rebind<_Rb_tree_node<_Val> >::other _Node_allocator;
```

---

A typical usage of this mechanism is to exploit some *memory pool*-based allocator, which might considerably speed-up node allocations. However, beware that this technique is, generally, not straightforward. For instance, with `std::unordered_map`, the (rebound) allocator type is used both for allocation of nodes and allocation of the array of buckets. In the `allocate` member function, one then needs to distinguish both allocation types and use memory pooling just for allocation of nodes.

With `std::map`, there is no array of buckets, so, theoretically, the allocator should be used only for allocation of nodes. However, I am not sure whether this is guaranteed by the Standard.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had tried it, it works, I need to know the size of the std::map node to pre-calculate the poll memory size.